# How to set `creation_time` in bazel `lang_image`

Tags: python, docker, bazel

Using bazel [rules_docker](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker) I could create a docker image for my python app like with:

```
py_image(
  name = "app_img",
  main = "app.py",
  srcs = ["app.py"],
)
```

But the image created with `bazel run :app -- --norun` is 50 years old according to `docker image ls`. According to the documentation of [container_image](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker#container_image-1), the date can be set using the attributes `stamp` and `creation_time`. If I try to add those in the `py_image` rule above, I get the error "no such attribute 'creation_time' in 'py_binary' rule". How can I set the date of images created with `py_image`?

Answer (score 1):

I tried `creation_time` as an attribute of `container_image` and it works well. `py_image` is a macro that reinjects its attributes in `py_binary` so this is why it fails.  You can either use `creation_time` in the base image you provide to `py_image` or use a stamping script that you specify in your build command or `.bazelrc`.

```
build --workspace_status_command=./path/to/some_script.sh
```

And the script can look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo BUILD_TIMESTAMP 1598918400
```

Hope this helps.